# Key r's mechanism in Vim

Tags: vim

Given the following text

```
7, 11,13,17, 19,23,29,
↑
my cursor is here
```

when I press `wr<Enter>`, Vim replaces comma and the space right after that with a line break, the result becomes:

```
7
11,13,17, 19,23,29,
```

I thought that only comma gets replaced.

What's the mechanism behind this?

Comment: Same reason putting the cursor on the space and doing `i<Enter>` will delete the space, I guess: not leaving leading spaces.

Comment: Try to load vim this way: `vim -u NONE -N`

Comment: @romainl Of course I checked help page before posting here. Excerpt from help. "r{char}: Replace the character under the cursor with {char}. If {char} is a <CR> or <NL>, a line break replaces the character". According to this, only comma got replaced by a line break. I wonder about what happened with that space before 11.

Comment: @SergioAraujo In non-compatible mode, that space before 11 remains. No mention of this weird behavior in Vim help.

Comment: try setting `set nocindent` and try again

Comment: Read again: *When `{char}` is a `<CR>` or `<NL>`, Vim performs autoindenting. This works just like deleting the characters that are replaced and then doing "`i<CR><Esc>`".*.